# Convert EnumProperty to be usable in prop_search

Tags: objects, interface, properties, collections

I want to make a list of the names of all Objects and Collections in the scene searchable via `prop_search`.
I have the generated name list as an EnumProperty, but `prop_search` only allows a CollectionProperty. I could use `prop` instead of `prop_search`, but that generates an awfully long list without the possibility so search it by typing.

Here is the EnumProperty:

```
Scene.ar_objects = EnumProperty(
    name="Allowed objects and collections",
    description="List of all collections and objects combined",
    items=get_object_list,
)
```

Here is how I would like to call this property:

```
row = layout.row(align=True)
row.prop_search(item, 'obj_name', context.scene, "ar_objects")
```

This list needs to be up-to-date all the time with the current objects and collections in the scene. This is easily achievable with the update parameter of the EnumProperty, but from what I can see, CollectionProperty doesn't have this.

So how can I convert the EnumProperty into a list searchable with `prop_search`?